# Transport in Georgia. Cheap or expensive?

Tags: europe, international-travel, eu, georgia-country, eastern-europe

How is the transport system in Georgia? Is it cheap or expensive? Do cabs charge by some meter of fixed fares or do they charge a lot?

Comment: I don't really know how to answer this question in a helpful way, I think you should make it more specific. But I think the best (and really only) way to go is to get yourself a good guide book which contains a.) average prices for common taxi routes (normally from the marshrutka stop in some town to nearby sights), b.) timetables and prices for marshrutkas between different cities.

Comment: How much is cheap? How much is expensive?

Answer (score 1):

According to [TripAdvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Travel-g294195-c17519/Tbilisi:Georgia:Taxis.And.Rental.Cars.html):

> Taxis and rental cars are both available for visitors to Tbilisi.
> However, both of these transportation options have certain advantages
> as well as disadvantages.
>
> Taxis are a great way of getting around the immediate city, but if
> planning on traveling much further, consider an alternative form of
> transportation (see the Trip Advisor Getting Around page).  Fares are
> very affordable, and should never cost more than a few dollars USD.
> Generally, taxis will be waiting outside of major public areas such as
> airports, train stations, bus stations, and large hotels.  If outside
> of these areas, the best way to get a taxi is to ask a hotels or
> restaurants for their help in arranging a ride.
>
> Most taxis are just cars by private individuals. There are very few
> taxi companies with reliable fleets and service levels.  Almost no
> taxis have taxi meter, so you should negotiate the price before
> starting your ride to avoid surprises.
>
> A personal vehicle is the most convenient form of transportation
> available in Tbilisi, as it allows the greatest freedom and
> flexibility in travel.   The Public Transportation around the city is
> sufficient, but it does not go everywhere.   First time visitors to
> the country should investigate the driving rules of Georgia before
> deciding to get behind the wheel of a car.

So you should be able to find sufficient transportation for an affordable cost.